# Does it also make sense to say "Not to put too fine a point on it, if you don't snooze, you lose."

Tags: meaning-in-context

In *Why We Sleep*, the author emphasizes the importance of sleep by saying "Not without putting too fine a point on it, if you don't snooze, you lose." Does it also make sense to say "Not to put  too fine a point on it, if you don't snooze, you lose." This is what I would have said.

Answer (score 1):

**Not to put too fine a point on it** is indeed the usual form of the expression. Google Ngrams doesn't bring up *any* results for *Not without putting too fine.* It must be an eccentric coinage by this author.